# How did cosmologists calculate the small density of dark energy in our universe?

Tags: cosmology, dark-energy, cosmological-constant

I've seen the number a few times (138 x10 to the power of -123) but i haven´t found how scientists calculated it. Max Tegmark mentions it in his research paper about multiverse types as representing the cosmological constant in Planck units

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dark energy density in the universe is a concordance result, based on several pieces of independent information- the power spectrum of spatial structure in the cosmic microwave background, the redshift-distance raltiinship derived from high redshift Type Ia supernovae, baryon acoustic oscillations, models of cosmic structure formation, primordial abundances and so on.

The value is about 0.7 of the energy density required for a "flat" universe - the so-called critical density. This is about $6\times 10^{-10}$ Joules per cubic metre.